# Slideshow software for handling 1000000+ photos

Tags: software-recommendation, slideshow

Looking for a software with the following requirements:

- Can handle million+ photos,
- Willing to pay for it up to €200 / $250-300,
- I do not want any software that creates only videos of slideshows
- must be able to handle large collection
- transition effects not required, but would be nice
- the photos are not in one folder, but scattered.
- ability to play music is not required.

What I tried:

- I have tried Irfanview, it crashed unless I do it folder by folder by 500k it gets clunky and it takes a full minute to do a small folder of 5000.
- Tried 4-5 other software which were just real bad.
- Tried a software called Cslide, great software, maybe 200kb large, made by an "amateur" programmer with skills, forgot the website but it does a large collection without loading like in Irfanview.
- Windows 7 default slideshow doesn't even try, it loads then stops cause it can't handle it all.

Comment: What is the final goal? That is, how do you expect to show/view 1 million photos? Even if each photo is only shown for 1 second, that's still 11+ days of non-stop photos!

Comment: Hey friend, my goal is for the photos to randomly play. I have no intention to sitting through it all :D

Comment: Considering that _no one_ will likely sit through 11+ days of photos, why do you need to handle that many? Where will the slideshow be displayed?

Comment: Slideshow is for home use. I just want it to be as random as possible that's why I want to cover my entire collection in it.

Comment: Can't you copy a small proportion of your images to another folder at random and then run the slideshow from there? That way the software wouldn't need to be able to handle so many images.

Comment: Even if I did only 10% of it , it'd be 350 GB of copies. Why does it need to handle the images? I've been downloading and trying out many slideshow softwares the past few hours. There are tiny simple softwares there that played and entire harddisk without them loading first, picking them randomly on the go.

Comment: So far the programs called Simply Slideshow and Wildbit Viewer are on top between 15 ish programs tested so far. Will keep this updated if another software takes their top spots. Can anyone that uses ACDSee Photo Manager and/or Zoner Photo Studio comment on them and their ability to play large collections.

Comment: MycView IS AMAZING! It does the entire disk and superfast, only downside: I couldn't find a random option for the slideshow!

Comment: If you're genuinely willing to pay $250-300 for it, a lot of devs would be happy to code you something for that price. You're more than welcome to get in touch with me if you wish (no contact details because I don't want to spam p.se, but if you comment here, we can find some way of contacting each other).

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi perhaps we see a wildly different scope here, but as a developer if I were offered $300 to build some sort of slideshow tool like this I would laugh so hard I wouldn't be able to get out a "no!"

Comment: @DanWolfgang: I see this as a fairly simple random photo viewer that works in full-screen mode. No transitions, no music, etc makes it as simple as using the right library to display images in a full-screen window.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) rather than photography, and there's a whole SE site for that.

Answer (score 0):

Resource Space should do it for you. Free application unless you want support. Web based. links to pictures are stored in a MySQL database (don't think it has to be the actual file). Professional piece of software, built for massive volumes, so you should be OK.

You can find most of the info at: http://www.resourcespace.org/ and go from there.

Comment: Does it do slideshows?  Don't see any mention of them

Comment: Sorry, ages since I set it up. They're through a plugin. I found this one in a bit of a rush but I think there are others around.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/resourcespace/27TWOon_7sw

Answer (score 0):

Taking a different approach to your problem, I have been using an Apple TV to view and share photos. I have a Shared Photo Stream set as a screensaver, and whenever playing music (or manually starting a slideshow) I see a constant display of photos on my TV, rotating through all of them in that specific Shared Photo Stream. I've been slowly adding my favorites to it and it's been a great way to view them.

I have no experience, but I suspect Roku, Google Chromecast, etc, offer the same capability.